# Why I am seeing this error "one or more matched elements are not visible" when click on steps in cypress?

Tags: testing, cypress

When I click on one of the cypress history steps it does not highlight the element in the DOM that is being rendered, I can also see a crossed out eye icon and when I put the course in the steps it gives two messages: "one or more matched element are not visible" and "printed output in your console".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJbkR.png)

The item is supposed to be highlighted on the screen.